# On Javascript Modules

Tags: javascript, module, closures

So, I'll be honest, my javascript understanding has not been the best. I am used to manipulating the DOM and thats about it. Recently I dove into You don't know javascript series to improve my knowledge and understanding.

They bring up the concepts of closure. Which I am very familiar with. However I have never encountered module pattern before nor used it. I am referring to [this example](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/up%20%26%20going/ch2.md#modules). I immediately tried making a working example of my own as I learn by doing. This is the example I came up with. It *does not work*.

```
function vehicle(){
  var wheels, doors;

  function findType(wheels, doors){
      var numberOfWheels = wheels;
      var numberOfDoors = doors;
      var type;

      switch(numberOfWheels | numberOfDoors){
        case 4 | 2:
          type = "sports car";
        break;
        case 4 | 4:
          type = "sedan";
        break;
        case 18 | 2:
        case 18 | 4:
          type = "tractor-trailer";
        break;
        default:
          type = "vehicle";
      }
  }
  return type;
}

var civic = vehicle();
console.log(civic.findType(4,4));
```

My expectation is that the console should return the type of "sedan" for civic. However, I am met with nothing. I don't exactly understand why. Any feedback would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the [The Revealing Module Pattern](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript). The module function returns an object that exposes the methods that you can use with this module.

```js
function vehicle() {
  var wheels, doors;

  // a mdoule method
  function findType(wheels, doors) {
    var numberOfWheels = wheels;
    var numberOfDoors = doors;
    var type;

    // the method returns the result
    switch (numberOfWheels | numberOfDoors) {
      case 4 | 2:
        return "sports car";
        break;
      case 4 | 4:
        return "sedan";
        break;
      case 18 | 2:
      case 18 | 4:
        return "tractor-trailer";
        break;
      default:
        return "vehicle";
    }
  }

  // the api of the module
  return {
    findType: findType
  };
}

var civic = vehicle();
console.log(civic.findType(4, 4));
```

PS - read [Adi Osmani's Learning JavaScript Design Patterns](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/) for in depth review of various patterns.

Comment: Thank you for this wonderful reply and linked resources. I didn't grasp that it was an object returning the methods.

Comment: Welcome :) If you want to learn JS, I also recommend JavaScript: The Good Parts, and [JavaScript Allongé, the "Six" Edition](https://leanpub.com/javascriptallongesix/read).